# Xamarin Forms custom control BindableLayout items not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a simple custom control to show tab-like items. The item data is not being shown. Sometimes, if I change the xaml while the app is running, the items will show, seeming to indicate that the data binding is correct.

TabBar.xaml

```
<ContentView xmlns="namespaces..."
     x:Class="MyApp.Classes.Controls.TabThing"
     x:Name="TabBar">

<ContentView.Content>
    <FlexLayout Grid.Row="0"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Source={x:Reference TabBar}}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Value.TabName}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                    <Frame x:Name="Underline" BackgroundColor="Black" CornerRadius="0" HeightRequest="4"></Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

The Control Class

```
    public partial class TabThing : ContentView
{
    public SortedDictionary<TabIdentifier, TabItem> Tabs { get; set; } = new SortedDictionary<TabIdentifier, TabItem>();

    public TabItem Selection { get; set; }

    public TabThing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Tabs.Clear();
        Tabs.Add(TabIdentifier.Assignments, new TabItem(TabIdentifier.Assignments, Strings.Assignments, typeof(View.MyView)));
        ... etc, have also tried this in OnParentSet
    }
}
```

The item class, if it is of interest

```
    public partial class TabItem
{
    public TabIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public Type DestinationType { get; set; }

    public TabItem(TabIdentifier id, string tabName, Type destinationType)
    {
        Identifier = id;
        TabName = tabName;
        DestinationType = destinationType;
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why my items are not rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and met the same problem. You can try to use the following binding code and it worked in my project.

Set the binding context in the ContentView's constructor:

```
    public TabThing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Tabs.Clear();
        Tabs.Add(TabIdentifier.Assignments, new TabItem(TabIdentifier.Assignments, Strings.Assignments, typeof(View.MyView)));
        
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

And binding the itemsource in the xaml:

```
<FlexLayout Grid.Row="0"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
```

**Note:**I also used the `BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={Type ContentView}}, Path= Tabs}">`  and `BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference TabBar} Path= Tabs}"`, but the relative binding still not worked.

**Update:**

I find the cause. Because the SortedDictionary is not observable, so the `FlexLayout` will not update the UI when you call the `Tabs.Add`.
The data binding excutes before you call the `Tabs.Add` and the binding value is an empty **SortedDictionary**. So you can try the following solution:

1. Use the **ObservableCollection** instead of the **SortedDictionary**.
2. Put the `InitializeComponent();` at the end of the constructor, such as:

```
    public TabThing()
    {
        Tabs.Clear();
        Tabs.Add(TabIdentifier.Assignments, new TabItem(TabIdentifier.Assignments, Strings.Assignments, typeof(View.MyView)));

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I abandoned this approach due to time, but I will need the information for other things. I appreciate it.